# I believe I have a Function Argument Issue

Tags: python

For the most part all of my code seems to be working fine. The code is a text-based game. When I collect all of the items it fuctions correctly without errors. But if I go to directly to Caslte Black without collecting all the items it finishes with the proper message, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users....................", line 38, in <module>
    city_item = cities[current_city][0]
KeyError: 'Castle Black'
```

Here is my code.

```
print("Welcome to the GOT: Winter is Coming Text Based Game")

player_name = input("What is your name Lord Commander? ")

print("\nIntroduction:")
print("      Sir " + player_name + ", as Lord Commander of the Kingsguard")
print("      you are to visit 10 cities across Westeros and Essos, and you MUST")
print("      collect the item from each city to win the game and defeat the Night King.")
print("   Once you collect all the items you automatically win the game defeating the Night King.")
print("      If you confront the Night King without all 10 items, you will perish and")
print("      all of Westeros and Essos will be doomed!")
print("\nGame Play Directions:")
print("   To move in a direction you will be prompted to chose either North, South, East or West")
print("   To collect an item, you will be prompted to enter 'Y' for 'YES' or 'N' for 'NO'.")
print("\nYou are now ready to begin your quest Lord Commander " + player_name + "!\n\n\n")

cities = {"King's Landing": [None, ["North", "South", "East", "West"]],
         "Casterly Rock": ["The Oathkeeper Sword", ["South", "East"]],
         "Highgarden": ["A Golden Rose", ["North"]],
         "Sunspear": ["A Viper", ["North", "East"]],
         "Great Pyramid Meereen": ["Drogon the Dragon", ["West"]],
         "Dragonstone": ["Dragon Glass", ["North", "West"]],
         "Pyke": ["The Iron Fleet", ["East"]],
         "The Twins": ["A Letter of Passage", ["North", "South", "East", "West"]],
         "The Eyrie": ["A Falcon", ["South", "West"]],
         "The Dreadfort": ["Lord Bolton's Army", ["West"]],
         "Winterfell": ["Ghost the Dyer Wolf", ["South", "East", "West"]]
         }

inventory = []
current_city = "King's Landing"

while True:
    if current_city == "Castle Black":
        print("You have been defeated by the Night King! The Realm is doomed!")

    print("Lord Commander, you are currently in", current_city, ".")
    city_item = cities[current_city][0]
    print("The current room has", city_item)

    if city_item != None:
        option = input("Do you want collect " + city_item + "? (Y/N): ") .upper()
        if option in ['Y', 'YES']:
            inventory.append(city_item)
            cities[current_city][0] = None

    print("Collected items: ", inventory)

    if len(inventory) == 10:
        print("\nCONGRATULATIONS!")
        print("You have collected all the items and have defeated the Night King!\n")
        break

    direction = input("Which direction do you want to go? (North, South, East, West): ")

    while direction not in cities[current_city][1]:
        print("You cannot go that way from " + current_city + ". Please try another direction.")
        direction = input("Which direction do you want to go? (North, South, East, West): ")

    if current_city == "King's Landing":
        if direction == "North":
            next_city = "The Twins"
        elif direction == "South":
            next_city = "Sunspear"
        elif direction == "East":
            next_city = "Dragonstone"
        else:
            next_city = "Casterly Rock"

    elif current_city == "The Twins":
        if direction == "North":
            next_city = "Winterfell"
        elif direction == "South":
            next_city = "King's Landing"
        elif direction == "East":
            next_city = "The Eyrie"
        else:
            next_city = "Pyke"

    elif current_city == "Sunspear":
        if direction == "North":
            next_city = "King's Landing"
        else:
            next_city = "Great Pyramid Meereen"

    elif current_city == "Great Pyramid Meereen":
        next_city = "Sunspear"

    elif current_city == "Casterly Rock":
        if direction == "South":
            next_city = "Highgarden"
        else:
            next_city = "King's Landing"

    elif current_city == "Highgarden":
        next_city = "Casterly Rock"

    elif current_city == "Dragonstone":
        if direction == "North":
            next_city = "The Eyrie"
        else:
            next_city = "King's Landing"

    elif current_city == "The Eyrie":
        if direction == "South":
            next_city = "Dragonstone"
        else:
            next_city = "The Twins"

    elif current_city == "Pyke":
        next_city = "The Twins"

    elif current_city == "Winterfell":
        if direction == "South":
            next_city = "The Twins"
        elif direction == "East":
            next_city = "The Dreadfort"
        else:
            next_city = "Castle Black"

    elif current_city == "The Dreadfort":
        next_city = "Winterfell"

    current_city = next_city
    print("My Lord, you have moved to", current_city, ".\n")

print("\nThank you for saving the Realm!")
```

When I change the argument from 0 to 1 and start the game over

```
city_item = cities[current_city][1]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\............................", line 42, in <module>
    option = input("Do you want collect " + city_item + "? (Y/N): ") .upper()
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I am unsure which way I should go from here.

Comment: There is no entry in the `cities` dictionary for Castle Black.  Should there be?

Comment: @JohnGordon based on the statement being printed, it looks like that's supposed to end the game/loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask] as you get your bearings here. It would also be a good idea to read about what constitutes a [mre] for code here; when you have a bug in your code, you want to reduce the code down to the smallest self-contained code possible that's still readable and reproduces the issue. We don't need a dictionary of eleven locations and their logic for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first condition in the loop, add a `break` or wrap the rest in an `else`. You're trying to access `cities["Castle Black"]`, hence the `KeyError`.

Comment: Zac, thank you so much for your help. I can't believe I missed that. Always good to get another set of eyes on it.